# tiemout for a function that waits indefiinitely (like listen())

Tags: c, multithreading, time, listen

I'm not quite sure if it's possible to do what I'm about to ask so I thought I'd ask.

I have a multi-threaded program where threads share a memory block to communicate necessary information. One of the information is termination of threads where threads constantly check for this value and when the value is changed, they know it's time for `pthread_exit()`. One of the threads contains `listen()` function and it seems to wait indefinitely. This can be problematic if there are nobody who wants to make connection and the thread needs to exit but it can't check the value whether thread needs to terminate or not since it's stuck on `listen()` and can't move beyond.

```
while(1)
{
  listen();
  ...
  if(value == 1)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My logic is something like that if it helps illustrate my point better. What I thought would solve the problem is to allow listen() to wait for a duration of time and if nothing happens, it moves on to next statement. Unfortunately, none of two args of `listen()` involves time limit. I'm not even sure if I'm going about the right way with multi-threaded programming, I'm not much experienced at all. So is this a good approach? Perhaps there is a better way to go about it? Thanks for any insightful comments.

EDIT: just to clarify a little, the reason `listen()` is in the while loop is that this is a server and will be connected to multiple clients at a time.

Comment: You need to call `listen()` just once, then call `accept()` in the loop. `accept()` is the one that blocks, so see some good responses below that suggest using `select()`/`poll()`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I read up on `select()/poll()` but I have more questions. Someone below (nos & slacker) said listen() marks the socket ready. Is there more to it than just marking it passive? How does it track backlogs then? I think what you are suggesting is that accept() would be called when select()/poll() returns that there is a socket to read? Could you suggest any internet literature regarding this topic? I've read opengroup manuals and beej's guide and such.. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set the socket to non-blocking, and wait for events using [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)/[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or similar - select/poll allows you to set a timeout.

Note that listen() doesn't block, it just marks the socket ready to handle incoming connecions - accept() would be the next step, that does block.

Comment: I thought listen() was waiting for incoming connection? I am using select() to check packets from multiple sockets though (because this is for a server and there will be multiple clients trying to connect) and that's for already established connections.

Comment: @Fantastic Fourier:
No, `listen()` only marks the socket as a passive "listening" socket, and returns immediately. You have to call `accept()` later to create the real connection (which may block, iff the listening socket is blocking).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I'm understanding it quite right. I get that I use accept() after listen() returns. If I were to use select/poll, I should discriminate whether the newly received data is from a new connection or not and then use accept() for a new connection?

Comment: Yes.  Add the listening socket to the `readfds` set in `select()`, and if it's set when `select()` returns, then you can call `accept()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a signal from the other thread (the one that changes the value to 1). It will make the listen function return with the EINTR error code.

Comment: Personnally I wouldn't complicate things with signals, threading alone is difficult enough.

Comment: Sorry I'm rather inexperienced in multi-threading, how would I go about sending signals between threads?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you need to set the timeout with [`setsockopt()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setsockopt.html), and check errno after `listen()` fails to see if it's a timeout or a serious error.

To me it seems that it should be doable to call `listen()` only once if you always use the same connection socket.
But maybe you'll have the same problem with `accept()`.

Comment: The problem is that this is a server program and is waiting (though listen()) for incoming client connections that haven't been established yet (and will establish using accept() )